# How can I do a UML Schema from a JSON file?

Tags: json, uml

Hello I have this JSON file :

```
{
    "Hello": "",
    "Olá": [
        {
            "Hour": "00:04:35",  
            "hotel": [""],
        }
    ]
    "Ciao" : [
        {
            "Hour": "02:36:52"
        }
    ]
}
```

And actually I am trying to convert this JSON file to an UML file.

Could you help me please ? :)

I thought of this :

Solution

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some code to show you tried? Also, The picture should be added directly to the post rather than with a link.

Comment: Your solution is not a valid UML diagram. Please first read more about classes and associations. If I would give you a solution, you probably wouldn't understand it due to your lack of UML knowledge.

Comment: I would suggest you first think what UML diagrams you want to show and why. Also read something about drawing UML in general since your proposal is not a valid UML at all.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at JSONDiscoverer http://som-research.uoc.edu/tools/jsonDiscoverer/#/

(the site includes also the technical details on how the UML model is created)

Answer (score 0):

gliffy diagrams can do it, actually is the original format to save files